# adding a method to non-restful routes in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

i would like to perform an action on some of my routes, the problem is they are not in a 'resources' block because I need named methods for each. I want to be able to toggle the state of each an attribute in each item in an index type view. I wwas attempting to incorporate [this](http://buckybits.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/simple-ajax-property-toggle-in-rails-30.html) tutorial.

```
  devise_for :admins  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  root 'home#index'
  resources :entries, :only => [:index, :new, :create] 
  namespace :admin do 
    namespace :entries do
      match :pending, :via => [:get, :post], :collection => { :toggle_approve => :put}
      match :rejected, :via => [:get, :post], :collection => { :toggle_approve => :put}
      match :approved, :via => [:get, :post], :collection => { :toggle_approve => :put}
    end
  end
```

entries controller

```
class Admin::EntriesController < ApplicationController

  expose(:entries){@entries}


  def index
  end

  def show
  end

  def approved 
    @entries = Photo.with_approved_state
  end

  def pending
    @entries = Photo.with_pending_state 
  end

  def rejected
    @entries = Photo.with_rejected_state
  end

  def toggle_approve  
    @a = Photo.find(params[:id])  
    @a.toggle!(:workflow_state)  
    render :nothing => true  
  end
```

rake routes

```
                   Prefix Verb     URI Pattern                       Controller#Action
        new_admin_session GET      /admins/sign_in(.:format)         devise/sessions#new
            admin_session POST     /admins/sign_in(.:format)         devise/sessions#create
    destroy_admin_session DELETE   /admins/sign_out(.:format)        devise/sessions#destroy
           admin_password POST     /admins/password(.:format)        devise/passwords#create
       new_admin_password GET      /admins/password/new(.:format)    devise/passwords#new
      edit_admin_password GET      /admins/password/edit(.:format)   devise/passwords#edit
                          PATCH    /admins/password(.:format)        devise/passwords#update
                          PUT      /admins/password(.:format)        devise/passwords#update
cancel_admin_registration GET      /admins/cancel(.:format)          devise/registrations#cancel
       admin_registration POST     /admins(.:format)                 devise/registrations#create
   new_admin_registration GET      /admins/sign_up(.:format)         devise/registrations#new
  edit_admin_registration GET      /admins/edit(.:format)            devise/registrations#edit
                          PATCH    /admins(.:format)                 devise/registrations#update
                          PUT      /admins(.:format)                 devise/registrations#update
                          DELETE   /admins(.:format)                 devise/registrations#destroy
                     root GET      /                                 home#index
                  entries GET      /entries(.:format)                entries#index
                          POST     /entries(.:format)                entries#create
                new_entry GET      /entries/new(.:format)            entries#new
    admin_entries_pending GET|POST /admin/entries/pending(.:format)  admin/entries#pending {:collection=>{:toggle_approve_article=>:put}}
   admin_entries_rejected GET|POST /admin/entries/rejected(.:format) admin/entries#rejected {:collection=>{:toggle_approve_article=>:put}}
   admin_entries_approved GET|POST /admin/entries/approved(.:format) admin/entries#approved {:collection=>{:toggle_approve_article=>:put}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had to understand the difference between member and collections. collections are routes additional to a resource (eg, the restful actions). members are extra routes which can perform actions on their the block.

This...

```
resources :entries, :only => [:index, :new, :create]
  namespace :admin do
    resources :entries do
      get :pending, on: :collection
      get :approved, on: :collection
      get :rejected, on: :collection
      member do 
        get :toggle_approve_field
        get :toggle_reject_field
      end
    end 
  end
```

yielded this rake routes

```
entries GET    /entries(.:format)                                entries#index
                                 POST   /entries(.:format)                                entries#create
                       new_entry GET    /entries/new(.:format)                            entries#new
           pending_admin_entries GET    /admin/entries/pending(.:format)                  admin/entries#pending
          approved_admin_entries GET    /admin/entries/approved(.:format)                 admin/entries#approved
          rejected_admin_entries GET    /admin/entries/rejected(.:format)                 admin/entries#rejected
toggle_approve_field_admin_entry GET    /admin/entries/:id/toggle_approve_field(.:format) admin/entries#toggle_approve_field
 toggle_reject_field_admin_entry GET    /admin/entries/:id/toggle_reject_field(.:format)  admin/entries#toggle_reject_field
                   admin_entries GET    /admin/entries(.:format)                          admin/entries#index
                                 POST   /admin/entries(.:format)                          admin/entries#create
                 new_admin_entry GET    /admin/entries/new(.:format)                      admin/entries#new
                edit_admin_entry GET    /admin/entries/:id/edit(.:format)                 admin/entries#edit
                     admin_entry GET    /admin/entries/:id(.:format)                      admin/entries#show
                                 PATCH  /admin/entries/:id(.:format)                      admin/entries#update
                                 PUT    /admin/entries/:id(.:format)                      admin/entries#update
                                 DELETE /admin/entries/:id(.:format)                      admin/entries#destroy
```

It took a lot of faffing around and I not sure I'd be able to do it upon request without more headache but I certainly have a better idea of rails routing all together. Thanks for the help from @RichPeck

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where the `collection` option is from (I literally can't find reference to it anywhere)

Implementing non-resourceful routes is actually relatively simple:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :entries, only: [:index, :new, :create] do
    collection do
       match :pending, via: [:get, :post]  #-> domain.com/entries/pending
       match :rejected, via: [:get, :post] #-> domain.com/entries/rejected
       match :approved, via: [:get, :post] #-> domain.com/entries/approved
    end
end
```

I don't understand the `collection` option - I don't think that belongs in your routes. Although having thought about it, I guess you're trying to make it so that if you receive a request to `domain.com/entries/toggle_approve_article/pending` you'll want to handle the reqeust?

If that's the case, why not just do this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :entries, only: [:index, :new, :create] do
    put :toggle_approve #-> domain.com/entries/15/toggle_approve
    collection do
       match :pending, via: [:get, :post]  #-> domain.com/entries/pending
       match :rejected, via: [:get, :post] #-> domain.com/entries/rejected
       match :approved, via: [:get, :post] #-> domain.com/entries/approved
    end
end
```

Comment: yeah that's pretty much it. I hacked away at it for hours last night and cracked it, I'll post below.